# Trigger a Database update after Gathr pipeline completes

Tags: jdbc, bigdata, etl

I am an ETL developer using Gathr to create my use cases. Currently, I am looking for a way to update the database after my pipeline completes its execution in Gathr, and I need to learn how to do it. Now I'm stuck. Would anyone be able to help me out? I have created one use case using S3 as a source and JDBC as a Target and performed some transformation in between.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's the detailed answer -**

In Gathr, post-actions can trigger a database update task after ETL pipeline completion. These include database updates, data validation, and custom operations.
Here are the steps to perform post actions in Gathr:
Configure the emitter with the necessary details for data emission when designing the pipeline. Then, follow these steps to define post-action tasks:

**Step 1:** Complete the desired emitter's configuration and navigate to the Post Actions section. Click on the "Add Actions" button.

[image: Step 1]

**Step 2:** Choose SQL or Stored Procedure from the dropdown menu.

[image: Step 2]

**Step 3:** Regardless of your choice, you must provide the database connection where the updates will be made after the pipeline runs. If you have already created a connection for the database, select it. Otherwise, click "Add New Connection" to create a new one.

[image: Step 3]

**Step 4:** Configure Action-Specific Settings.
Depending on the selected action, specific configuration options will be presented:

- If Action is SQL: A text box will appear for writing SQL queries.
  You can enter an SQL query to be executed after the pipeline runs.

[image: Action is SQL]

- If Action is Stored Procedure/Function:
  Choose between stored procedures and functions.

[image: Action is Stored procedure]

If Stored Procedure is selected, you will see a list of available stored procedures from the database. The list will help you choose the stored procedure you need.

[image: Stored Procedure]

If Function is selected, you will see a list of available functions from the database. The list will help you choose the function you need.

[image: Function]

**Step 5:** Map Parameters (For Stored Procedures/Functions)
If you have selected a stored procedure or function, you will be prompted to map the incoming data to the parameters of the function or stored procedure.

[image: Step 5]

To complete the process of configuring a database update trigger after the completion of a Gathr pipeline, do as follows:

1. Save the settings you have configured for your pipeline.
2. Initiate the pipeline run.
3. Once the pipeline run is complete, the database trigger you have configured will be executed based on your specified settings.
   Following these steps, you can configure a database update trigger for your Gathr pipeline.